# How to assign nested variables in a list into a new list or vector in R?

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a nested list which I converted from a JSON file. This list contains user IDs (strings), under each of the IDs I have other nested elements, integers, booleans, etc. I have sorted this list via list.sort by a specific integer called score. What I really want to have is to have a list or a vector that only includes these score values, preferably top 100. I don't care about the user IDs or any other data point. How do I do this? I am completely new to R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lapply and sapply functions iterate through the list. Iterated with lapply, used a function that returns the score value of the component.